# Deleting specific folders recursively

Tags: linux, rm

The folder structure is as below

```
A/B/C1/
A/B/C2/
X/B/C1/
X/B/C2/
```

I want to delete all C2 folders however keep C1 intact.

What is the correct command for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine: `rm -rf */*/C2/`
Please be careful, because it says nothing when deleteing all the files and folders recersively. If you want to be cautious, you can use: `rm -ri */*/C1/` instead which prompts for every deletion.

Comment: You are right. Thanks! But the correct one is `rm -rf */*/C2/` because I want to delete C2

Comment: Yes, I fixed that. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest method would be like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -name C2 -type d -exec rm -fr '{}' ';'
```

Comment: You should also provide a -mindepth of 3.